# How to make while loop for example 5 automatic registration account

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, qa-developer

How to make while loop for example 5 automatic registration account 
this is my code and I want to make an automatic python script for 5 registration account

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get("http://site.com")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Register')])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id('first_name').send_keys("joe");
driver.find_element_by_id('last_name').send_keys("joe");
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.page-columnMain > form > div.form-group > #email').send_keys("test@test.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.form-group.form-group--half > #password').send_keys("test2");
driver.find_element_by_id('password_confirmation').send_keys('test2');
driver.find_element_by_name("agree").click();
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='submit'])[2]").click();
```

Comment: for example i want username:test1,test2,test3,test4            password:test234 and for 4 different mails in my example test1@test.com  test2@test.com  test3@test.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method to perform the registration operation just like in the code below. Store the test data as you have mentioned in the comment above in some data-structure or file.

```
fanme | lname | email | username | password

fanme | lname | email | username | password
```

Call the below method for each test data.

```
private void perform_registration(Registration _reg) {
// your webdriver interaction goes here -- something like this
_fname.sendKeys(_reg.getFName()); 
_lname.sendkeys(_reg.getLName)
_email.sendKeys(_reg.getEmail()); 
    // other operation continues
}
```

This nothing to do with Selenium, this is plain simple language construct; how you organize your code, so that you get properly re-usable code which is easy to maintain.

Comment: I made like you show me txt file , and save like data.txt how to put in my program for my example up stare? i have in txt fname, lname, email, pass, repeat pass ?

Comment: fname|lname|email|pass how to make this prog with while loop?

Comment: Just an observation: The underscore on the argument and the getX methods names are not pythonic. Simply reg and get_file / get_name / get_email is the way.

Comment: First you have to read the external txt file and then retrieve the values separating by '/'. Now what you have is your test data in some python object. Pass them to your tests by a data provider(pytest or unittest has this mechanism - data driven testing).

Comment: The fname,lname etc are attributes of Registration object if you follow the above example. So you will be passing that object to your test method. Now you have the control how many number of times you want to run that method.

Comment: Regarding the third point, Registration is a plain simple model class which has the registration attributes and the getters and setters for that. So that you can query that class to get the registration attributes at any point of time. I understand getX() would not be pythonic. Try using python properties [link] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Hope you understood the concept.